# How to expand selection to containing block? (It is in fact called Smart Selection)

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode

I'm trying to re-do the C-w selection shortcut in Jetbrains's IDE.

Is there a way to select visually the whole containing block ?

for now, i use

```
nnoremap <C-w> <Esc>viw
vnoremap <C-w> <Esc>{v}
```

Which allow me to select current word, then current block. (That's already really nice though)

I know i could select multiple blocks with like `{{v}}`, but that would just catch adjacent blocks, and would not backtrack to parent block, and that plays poorly with new lines.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

---

It seems what I was looking for is called "smart selection", and there seem to be at least one vim extension that does that :

https://github.com/gcmt/wildfire.vim

[image: wildfire in use]

Comment: Are you looking for `vip` ? See [`:h text-objects`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#text-objects). Also I would advise to be careful remapping `<C-w>`  because it is a useful prefix for a lot of window related commands. And also you don't need to add `<Esc>` in your normal mode mapping since you are already in normal mode.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in way to do what you want. If none of the text objects mentioned in `:h text-objects` fit your needs, maybe you could have a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) which allows you to create your own.

Comment: @statox thank's for the c-w advice Its a shame we cant map control shift tab vs control tab. vip looks like what I want to achieve, but i mean some "recursive vip", if that would make sense ?
It seems like <Esc>{v} makes a better job selecting a whole block. But it goes too far now that I check it with a better language to test it against. Maybe I have to think about a way to go through repetition viw -> vV -> vip -> <Esc>{v}. The second mapping is a visual-mode one :p.

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineGuillaume I want to do the same. I am curious, what did you settle on?

Comment: Didn't find what I was looking for (I was hoping to replicate jetbrains' expand selection)

Comment: @SebastianNielsen https://github.com/gcmt/wildfire.vim it seems the word for what I was looking for is "smart selection", and I found a vim extension I did not look into yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slight change of workflow would be to type <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> as many times as necessary to jump to the start of the enclosing block, then <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> to visually select that entire block.

See [`:help [{`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%5B%7B) and [`:help %`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%25) for more details.

You can use these to implement your mappings:

```
nnoremap <C-W> [{V%
xnoremap <C-W> "_y[{V%
```

The visual mode mapping works by first yanking into the black hole register (see `:help quote_`), in order to exit visual mode leaving the cursor at the start of the previously selected block, and then selecting the next surrounding block with the same commands. I'm using `xnoremap` instead of `vnoremap` because the latter also applies in select mode, which you probably don't want.

[Like statox](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19027/how-to-expand-selection-to-containing-block/19028?noredirect=1#comment32964_19027), I'd recommend against using `<C-W>` for the lhs. You'd be better off finding another trigger for your mappings.

Comment: I'm letting the ticket open until tomorrow. What I synthetized is `%[{v]}`

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume See my edit for a mapping solution.

Comment: So now you are using a _ registry, that you yank ? What does that mean ?

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume See my edit for an explanation.